# how to pass a string from one uiviewcontroller to another

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have tried a bunch of different things and feel like I am missing something really small..

I am trying to pass a string to another view controller but when i NSLog it i get a return of (null)...

heres what It looks like, I have tried so many examples I am almost ready to give up..

```
//secondview.h
@interface SearchResultsViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSString *setRequestString;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *setRequestString;

//secondview.m
//...
@synthesize setRequestString;
//...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@", setRequestString);
}


//firstview.m
//...
#import "secondview.h"
//...
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    //--- Idendify selected indexPath (section/row)
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        //--- Get the subview ready for use
        secondview *sec = [[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondview" bundle:nil];
//...
        switch (indexPath.row)
        {
                case 0: sec.title = @"Manufacture";
                sec.setRequestString = [NSString stringWithString:@"yo"];
                break;
//...
```

etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a method in the class to which you want to send the data and call this method from the other class and pass the data as a parameter of the method. If u want keep it very simple u can try using NSUserDefaults. Hope this helps. Happy coding.... :)

Comment: Cheers this is what I ended up doing. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "switch (indexPath.row) { case 0:" is getting called? 
Try putting an NSLog in that case of your switch statement to make sure of that first.

Comment: positive, because the title of the new view is being set, and because I just NSLogged it to double check :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using a pretty uncommon object name; "setRequestString" should better be named "requestString". Otherwise your synthesized setter will be called "setSetRequestString".

-- rest removed as that was bullshit, sorry, its late over here ;) ----

Comment: sorry their was a.title their I shortened the method name so its not so confusing to everyone but accedenetly took that part out. so its **sec.title**

Comment: also, I have  tried removing the line where i set the title and it still dosnt work..

Comment: Okay thankyou for the help and time.. I think i am going to  give this another debug.. see whats happening.

Comment: I have just decided to make a function in my secondview and pass a string to that, Its now working.. weird I dunno why one would work and the other would not...